# Write an assembly programme to print the largest of two numbers

Tags: assembly, arm

Here is my code. We have to find the largest of the two numbers. I feel like I've messed up somewhere or that the code is incomplete.

```
A: .word 12
B: .word 24

load r1, [A]
load r1, [r1]
load r2, [B]
load r2, [r2]

blt r1, r2, end
mov r1, r2
load r1
end:
    bra +0
```

Any help would be encouraged

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  As for your question, the code you have shown does not assemble as ARM code.  Is it perhaps a different architecture?  If yes, please say so.  Also, please comment your code with what you think it does so it can be matched with what is actually does.  As is, you do not explain your thought process at all and it's very hard to give you effective help.

Answer (score 0):

Loading values into registers is done in two steps, first make a pointer to the variable, and then load the data from its address. Something like this:

```
ldr R0, =A //R0 is pointing to A
ldr R1, [R0] //load a word from the address pointed to by R0 into R1
```

Note: you can do ldr R0, [R0]

You cannot compare and branch in the same instruction. blt, r1, r2, end is an invalid instruction. You can compare and then branch based on the comparison results.

There are several ways to do a comparison, but the easiest is probably using the CMP instruction which compares two values. Compare the values in two registers that hold the values of A and B (in registers R1 and R2 for example).

```
CMP R1, R2
```

Finally, you can use a branch instruction with conditions such as BLT or BEQ, with the label of the target

```
BLT end
```

The pseudo code would look like this:

```
set up pointers
load values 
compare values
branch to the end if A<B
```